# Testing of Subscription Payment Option in Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, subscriptions

I need to test subscription payment option in my app using Google Play.

I've created test accounts for these purposes in Google Play Developer Console.

Static responses don't work with subscriptions.

So only way to test it is to actually purchase a weekly, monthly or a yearly subscription.

First thing to do is to change all subscription prices to lowest possible.

As I know, it is not recommended to use real credit card with test accounts.

I am trying to use Test Credit Card Account Numbers (see link given bellow), but any of them are not accepted by Google Play.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Expiration Date is a valid date in the future, but e.g. Visa 4111111111111111 (Credit Card Security Code is any number) and other Test Credit Card Account Numbers fail when I am trying to use them when I am testing my subscriptions.

**Can you tell me how can I avoid "invalid credit number" issue when I am trying to use Test Credit Card Account Numbers in Google Play?**

Thanks and Regards,